# Appropriate pattern for setting request object properties from POST request with MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, http-post

With incoming POST requests to my MVC3 application, I want to validate the incoming request parameters.  If an invalid parameter exists, an exception is thrown.

Given the following object:

```
public class ActionRequest
{
    public string ActionRequestPassword { get; set; }
    public bool EnableNewsfeedAppPool { get; set; }
}
```

With incoming post requests, I want to initialize the object with the appropriate properties via:

```
public class NewsfeedAppPoolController : Controller
{
    [ActionName("EnableAppPool"), AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [NoCache]
    public ActionResult EnableAppPool(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        Models.ActionRequest actionRequest = ValidatePOSTRequest(formCollection);

        // do things with actionRequest

        return null;
    }

    private Models.ActionRequest ValidatePOSTRequest(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        try
        {
            Type actionRequestType = typeof(Models.ActionRequest);
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;
            object systemActivatorObject = Activator.CreateInstance(actionRequestType);

            foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
            {

                propertyInfo = typeof(Models.ActionRequest).GetProperty(key);
                Type t = propertyInfo.PropertyType; // t will be System.String


                if (t.Name == "Int32")
                {
                    actionRequestType.GetProperty(key).SetValue(systemActivatorObject, Convert.ToInt32(formCollection[key]), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    actionRequestType.GetProperty(key).SetValue(systemActivatorObject, formCollection[key], null);
                }
            }

            return (Models.ActionRequest)systemActivatorObject;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        } 
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there can be any improvements made to this, or recommendations of how else to accomplish this in an efficient manner.

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Comment: You don't need `[ActionName]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate pattern is,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Employee employee)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     db.Save(employee);
     RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  return View();
}
```

Notes:

The `employee` instance is automatically created and populated by the **default model binder** from the values available in the request(form, querystrings, routedata and more)

When the **default model binder** binds the values to the model it also does the validation and store all the errors in the `ModelState` dictionary, so by checking the `ModelState.IsValid` you can know that whether the validation is succeeded or not.

To know more about model binding refer [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx).
To know more about model validation refer [this](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/4/model_validation_in_asp_net_mvc).

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net MVC already does all of this for you.
Just add a `Models.ActionRequest actionRequest` parameter to your action.

If you want to add additional validation logic, use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the default model binder which will take care of instantiating and binding the ActionRequest from the request parameters:

```
public class NewsfeedAppPoolController : Controller
{
    [ActionName("EnableAppPool"), AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [NoCache]
    public ActionResult EnableAppPool(ActionRequest actionRequest)
    {
        // do things with actionRequest

        return null;
    }
}
```